# SIGSEGV Spotlight error

Tags: macos, spotlight

My new MacBook Pro 2018 8 core on Mojave has some issues generating a proper Spotlight database. I tried the obvious methods of excluding the drive, re-including it, and the terminal commands for rebuilding Spotlight. Additionally I ran Disk Utility First Aid twice, which automatically restarted my machine each time during process (?!)

These are the constant errors coming up in system log, they are thrown around every second.

```
Dec  6 23:25:46 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.single.0A000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec  6 23:25:49 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.single.09000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000[4085]): Service exited due to SIGSEGV | sent by exc handler[4085]
```

When searching with Spotlight, the "Indexing" bar is constantly showing up, never progressing significantly. Some days later, still there.

I double clicked one of the `mdworker_shared` Process Names in Activity Monitor and clicked the tab "Open Files and Ports" which revealed this:

```
cwd
/
txt
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mdworker_shared
txt
/Library/Preferences/Logging/.plist-cache.laC3ZYuM
txt
/usr/share/file/magic.mgc
txt
/usr/lib/dyld
txt
/private/var/folders/7l/6j3svjhs13l39y6f96hmw_j40000gq/0/com.apple.LaunchServices-231-v2.csstore
0
/dev/null
1
/dev/null
2
/dev/null
3
/Users/username/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks/Books/.DS_Store
4
/Users/username/Music/iTunes/.DS_Store
5
/Users/username/Library/Group Containers/QA2G25RMZ4.com.wunderkinder/Wunderlist/.DS_Store
6
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/.DS_Store
7
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/.DS_Store
8
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/.DS_Store
```

---

The open files remain the same even after double-clicking the `mdworker_shared` process again.

So apparently there is an issue indexing the .DS_Store files?

Whats the catch?

Comment: I would start with [AHT - Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold D while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter attached.

Comment: @Allan I tried this to no avail, all seems fine.

Comment: Can you disable following app: `com.wunderkinder/Wunderlist` also the Magic process

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your Activity Monitor and post it to the question?  Specifically, look for the `mds` and `mdworker_shared` processes.

Comment: Also, the reason I asked you to run AHT was because SIGSEGV is a memory segmentation fault (access violation) that's triggered by hardware.

Comment: @Allan Here is the screenshot of the Activity Monitor. https://cl.ly/191f9aa1711a - is it correct that partly, the mdworker_shared processes are run by root, partly by _spotlight ?

Comment: Yes.  You are correct.  `mds` is the "parent" process to `mdworker` and `mdworker_shared`.  In your case, there appears to be a number of spawned processes.  Try force quitting `mds`

Comment: @Buscar웃 I trashed the folder Wunderlist which was shown as problematic. Then force quit the mdworker shared prodcesses associated with that folder. After this, the activity monitor looks like this: https://cl.ly/28b356d729cb which seems already to be better. Is this how it should look like?

Comment: This one came up as well in system.log - "SpotlightServerKit (0x7fffada6d5f0) and /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mds (0x103ded190). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined."

Comment: @Allan The problems still remain, no change whatsoever. Any new guesses?

Comment: I'm assuming you've rebooted you machine.  I'm still not convinced that you *don't* have a memory issue.  If possible, create a fresh install on a USB drive/flash (a 32GB stick is sufficent).  On a different Mac, boot that image and ensure that Spotlight is working.  Then bring that USB to the "problem" Mac and boot that.  See if Spotlight still works.  If it throws errors, you have an issue with the machine itself.

Comment: @Allan I just created a new partition on my internal drive, and tested with this new user. The spotlight issues are gone. Whats strange as well is: I have many processes called: mdworker_shared which come from user _spotlight. I did definitely NOT have _spotlight as a user on the freshly installed machine.

Comment: It appears you may have found the culprit...a bad install.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

From your report it looks like the Wondershare is a problem maker and slowing down the Spotlight.

```
/Users/username/Library/Group Containers/QA2G25RMZ4.com.wunderkinder/Wunderlist/.DS_Store
```

Shut the Wunderlist down.

You might want to consider giving the Spotlight a break so it can start over.

Turn it off

```
sudo mdutil -a -i off
```

this turns off indexing of files,

To turn indexing back on, run

```
sudo mdutil -a -i on
```

After this you could run the complete re-indexing of your hard drive **(be aware this could be an over night job)**, it will delete your Spotlight data base forcing it to start over.

```
sudo rm -rf /.Spotlight-V100/*
```

Comment: Hi @Buscar i know how to reset Spotlight, and have done many times. Its not that spotlight would not reindex, it just never finishes because of the problems described.

Comment: This problem is still open after some months. I will try to setup my computer again, from scratch. Hopefully that will solve the issues. Another thought is that the motherboard could be faulty. I have audio crackles constantly, which are sometimes referred to with a fault motherboard.